# React Navigation: Call a function of screen from its Navigator - Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I've been trying **to call a function which is in a screen of a navigator from its screen**.

To clarify the point, here is a snippet of my code...

```
//ScreenA.js
export default class ScreenA extends React.Component {
    showWarning(){
        this.setState({showWarning: true});
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.setState({showWarning: false});
        }.bind(this), 3000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <View  style={{backgroundColor : this.state.showWarning ? "#red" : "#blue"}}>
              {this.state.showWarning && <Warning />}
          </View>
        )
    }
}

//Nagigator.js
default export const Navigator = StackNavigator({
  ScreenA: {screen: ScreenA},
  ScreenB: {screen: ScreenB},
});

//App.js
export default class App extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit(qrCode){
        if(qrCodeIsInvalid){
            this.navigator.ScreenA.showWarning();
            //This is just a sudo code.
            //How do we call ScreenA.showWarning here?
        }
    }


    render() {
        let props = {/*some props here*/};            
        return (//This "ref" stops the application without describing any reason
            <Navigator screenProps={props} ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }}/>
        );
    }
}
```

There is an example of how to call a function from a navigation [*header*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377301/how-to-call-screen-component-class-method-from-react-navigation-header), but not from the class which `export`s the navigator.

I thought that each screen can be accessed via [ref](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/#Calling-Navigate-on-Top-Level-Component), but this causes an error without explaining what's happening.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?

Any advice will be appreciated.

**P.S.**

@ Nimrod Argov

Here are details of what I've been trying to achieve.

`ScreenA` has a QR code reader and `submit` function, which submits QR codes to `App.js`.

`App.js` has handleSubmit function, where submitted QR codes are sent to a server and labelled as either valid or invalid.

If a submitted QR code turns out to be invalid, `ScreenA` has to show a warning message and change its background colour **for 3 seconds**.

It might be achieved by having `App.js` pass a prop `{showWarning:true}` to `ScreenA` and pass `{showWarning:false}` in 3 seconds.

However, I thought it would be `ScreenA`'s responsibility to change its background colour. Thus, I set `setTimeout` and `setState` in the `showWarning()`.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to force something when maybe it's not the best idea. However, you're asking about the implementation. Could you elaborate about [what you're actually trying to achieve](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @NimrodArgov Thanks, I added details into the original description.

Answer (score 6):

I did it this way:

### ScreenA.js

While navigate to ScreenB, including the function you want to call.

```js
export default class ScreenA extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }
    doSomething() {
        this.setState({blah: true});
    }
    navigateToB() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
            doSomething: this.doSomething,
        });
    }
}
```

### ScreenB.js

So you can do this in ScreenB.

```js
const { state, setParams, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
const params = state.params || {};

params.doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't seem to work when the `navigation.navigate( )` is inside the header (i.e. `static navigationOptions`).

Comment: @Hiroki That's another topic about how to access `props.navigation`. There's an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43400151/react-native-react-navigation-how-do-i-access-a-components-state-from-static/45098153#45098153

Comment: Thank you so much. I +1ed on the post.

Comment: is this possible from screen A to screen C ?